# Having problems to run a umbraco site

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, controllers

I get this error, when I'm trying to run the site.
The controller type `UmbracoBootstrapProject.Controllers.SiteLayoutControllers` does not follow conventions, MVC Controller class names must be suffixed with the term 'Controller'

```
namespace UmbracoBootstrapProject.Controllers
{
    public class SiteLayoutControllers : SurfaceController
    {

        private const string PARTIAL_VIEW_FOLDER = "~/Views/Partials/SiteLayout/";
        public ActionResult RenderHeader()
        {
            return PartialView(PARTIAL_VIEW_FOLDER + "_Header.cshtml");
        }
        public ActionResult RenderFooter()
        {
            return PartialView(PARTIAL_VIEW_FOLDER + "_Footer.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have named your controller `SiteLayoutControllers` (plural) instead of `SiteLayoutController`. Changing it to the latter should fix it